# On typing character on drop down it is selecting any random match from options and triggering change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

Below is my code in backbonejs + coffeescript.

Scenario:
I open countries Drop down , I type 'i' to select countries starting with 'i'
Typing triggers change event from which the drop down gets closed

Expected:
Drop down should not be closed and it should highlight the countries starting with 'i'

I am trying to get a event which is triggered only on select of the options

Note: Have used jquery easy drop down [plugin link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Based-Drop-Down-Builder-EasyDropDown)

Backbonejs code -

```
class Brown.Views.Home.OperatorSignUp extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'change #country' : 'getState'

  getState: (event)->
    unless _.isEmpty($('#country').val())
      $('#state').html @statesTemplate(states: '')
```

HTML code -

```
<div class="form-group colCountry customSelectRow">
  <select  id='country' name='country' class="form-control search">
    <option value="" class="countryLabel">Country</option>
    <% _.each(countries, function(val, key, object){%>
      <option value='<%=key%>'><%=val%></option>
    <% }) %>
  </select>
  <label class="floatingLabel">Country</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing many times in my current project without issues. The only thing I can assume is that jquery easy drop down plugin is firing events when you don't want it to. Have you tried this without enabling the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of the plugin which I found at the link you provided, you can register a callback for onSelect while appluing easyDropdown on any select element as follows

```
$(function(){
    var $selects = $('id-for-select');

    $selects.easyDropDown({
        onSelect: function(selected){
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

So I guess you can use this instead of the change event.